# Unable to convert .h5 model to ONNX for inferencing through any means

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensorflow-serving, onnx

I built a custom model in .h5 from [Matterport's MaskRCNN implementation](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN). I managed to save the full model and not the weights alone using `model.keras_model.save()`, and assume it worked correctly.

I need to convert this model to ONNX to inference in Unity Barracuda, and I have been hitting several errors along the way.
I tried:

T1. .h5 to ONNX using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-convert-your-keras-model-to-onnx-8d8b092c4e4f) and the keras2onnx package, and I hit an error at:

```
model = load_model('model.h5')

Error:
ValueError: Unknown layer: BatchNorm
```

T2. Defining custom layers using [this GitHub code](https://github.com/vagomundo21/Save-Load-MaskRCNN-model):

```
 model = keras.models.load_model(r'model.h5', custom_objects={'BatchNorm':BatchNorm, 
'tf':tf, 'ProposalLayer':ProposalLayer, 
'PyramidROIAlign1':PyramidROIAlign1, 'PyramidROIAlign2':PyramidROIAlign2,
'DetectionLayer':DetectionLayer}, compile=False)

Error:
ValueError: No model found in config file.
ValueError: Unknown layer: PyramidROIAlign
```

T3. .h5 to .pb (frozen graph) and .pbtxt, and then from .pb to ONNX using tf2onnx after finding input and output nodes (seems to be only one of each?):

```
assert d in name_to_node, "%s is not in graph" % d
AssertionError: output0 is not in graph
```

T4. .h5 to SavedModel using tf-serving code [from here](https://github.com/moganesyan/tensorflow_model_deployment) and then `python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model exported_models\coco_mrcnn\3 --opset 15 --output "model.onnx"` to convert to ONNX:

```
ValueError: make_sure failure: variable mrcnn_detection/map/while/Enter already exists as state variable.
```

TLDR: **Is there a way to convert my .h5 model to ONNX through any direct/indirect means?** I have been stuck on this for days!

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
It seems that `keras.models.load_model()` throws the first two errors - wondering if there is a way I can work with the .pb/.pbtxt model, or a way around without using `load_model()`, or a way to solve the `load_model()` issue?

Edit 2:

[Code for T1](https://file.io/tp8AOZBISJNc):
custom dataset modified from [Matterport's MaskRCNN implementation](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN)

[Code for T4](https://file.io/ZEnstfO8t4Vs)

Answer (score 4):

Try converting it to saved model format and then to onnx.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


def get_model():
    # Create a simple model.
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32,))
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")
    return model

model = get_model()
# Train the model.
test_input = np.random.random((128, 32))
test_target = np.random.random((128, 1))
model.fit(test_input, test_target)

# Calling `save('my_model.h5')` creates a h5 file `my_model.h5`.
model.save("my_h5_model.h5")

# It can be used to reconstruct the model identically.
model = keras.models.load_model("my_h5_model.h5")
tf.saved_model.save(model, "tmp_model")
```

Then convert it using tf2onnx.

```
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model tmp_model --output "model.onnx"
```

Comment: Hi! keras.models.load_model() seems to be the function to throw errors in both (1) and (2)

Comment: It could be a problem with your custom model, I've updated my answer with a sample model.

Comment: Thanks! I tried [another way](https://github.com/moganesyan/tensorflow_model_deployment) to convert to savedModel using your suggestion. While converting that to onnx using tf2onnx.convert, I get this error - 
ValueError: make_sure failure: variable mrcnn_detection/map/while/Enter already exists as state variable.

Comment: could you provide a link to your full code?

Comment: Sure - I have edited the question to include the code and the SavedModel attempt

Comment: i'm getting No module named 'samples'

Comment: I also followed [this tutorial](https://thebinarynotes.com/how-to-train-mask-r-cnn-on-the-custom-dataset/) to help with the Matterport implementation - so my code is inside the directory ...Mask_RCNN/samples/custom. You may want to edit the import statement to reflect your directory structure, pointing to CustomConfig() of custom.py - hope that clarifies

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

via anaconda powershell console (execute as admin) :

**pip install tf2onnx**

**pip install onnxmltools**

and in a notebook (for example)

```html
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
import os
os.environ['TF_KERAS'] = '1'
import onnxmltools


model = load_model('[h5 path]')
onnx_model = onnxmltools.convert_keras(model) 

onnxmltools.utils.save_model(onnx_model, '[onnx path]')
```