# YOLO returns different results when executed in ONNX runtime

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, onnx

I'm trying to replicate the results this [Real-time Detection of Personal-Protective-Equipment (PPE) model](https://github.com/ciber-lab/pictor-ppe) besides the code they do provide the dataset and trained models on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19uUR6EJPQzMeK0YpsxRm51wMZzDmcsv6)

First I run the code with the original model, then I do it with the converted model, the problem is that the result I-m getting from both models doesn't even have the same shape, the original one is a list o vectors and the second one has only one vector instead of three

[image]

At the moment I-m testing it on google Colab with the below code:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from IPython.display import display, Math
from time import time

import sys
sys.path.append('../')

from drive.MyDrive.ONNX_demo.utils.image import letterbox_image, draw_detection
from drive.MyDrive.ONNX_demo.utils.model import yolo_body

from drive.MyDrive.ONNX_demo.utils.fixes import *
fix_tf_gpu()

import onnx
# Compute the prediction with ONNX Runtime
import onnxruntime as rt
import numpy

act_img = cv2.imread('drive/MyDrive/ONNX_demo/image/4.jpg')
image_shape = act_img.shape[:-1]
img = letterbox_image(act_img, (416,416))/255.
img = np.expand_dims(img, 0)

'''Show the image'''
plt.imshow( act_img[:,:,::-1] )
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
#########################
###### Classes
#########################
class_names = ['H', 'V', 'W']

anchor_boxes = np.array(
        [
        np.array([[ 76,  59], [ 84, 136], [188, 225]]) /32, # output-1 anchor boxes
        np.array([[ 25,  15], [ 46,  29], [ 27,  56]]) /16, # output-2 anchor boxes
        np.array([[ 5,    3], [ 10,   8], [ 12,  26]]) /8   # output-3 anchor boxes
        ],
        dtype='float64'
    )

input_shape  = (416, 416)

K.clear_session() # clear memory

# number of classes and number of anchors
num_classes = len(class_names)
num_anchors = anchor_boxes.shape[0] * anchor_boxes.shape[1]

# input and output
input_tensor = Input( shape=(input_shape[0], input_shape[1], 3) ) # input
num_out_filters = ( num_anchors//3 ) * ( 5 + num_classes )        # output

#######
## Prediction with the original model 
##############

## Build and load the model 
model = yolo_body(input_tensor, num_out_filters)

weight_path = 'drive/MyDrive/ONNX_demo/models/pictor-ppe-v302-a1-yolo-v3-weights.h5'

model.load_weights( weight_path )
yolo_pred = model.predict(img)
```

[image]

```
### Conver
# save the complete model:

tf.saved_model.save(model, "drive/MyDrive/ONNX_demo/models/save_model")

# convert it to ONNX format: 

python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model "drive/MyDrive/ONNX_demo/models/save_model" --output "drive/MyDrive/ONNX_demo/models/model.onnx"

### Inference with ONNX
sess = rt.InferenceSession("drive/MyDrive/ONNX_demo/models/model.onnx")
input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
label_name = sess.get_outputs()[0].name
yolo_pred =  sess.run([label_name], {input_name: img.astype(np.float32)})[0]
```

[image]

As part of convertion first I converted the model from HDF5 to save format in order of having the complete model stored and not only the weights as mentioned in this post: [Unable to convert .h5 model to ONNX for inferencing through any means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007059/unable-to-convert-h5-model-to-onnx-for-inferencing-through-any-means)